# Raspberry Pi bash cvlc internet radio

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi, vlc

I want to play internet radio with VLC.
I use `cvlc` command on terminal and it works.

```
cvlc http://5.20.223.18/relaxfm128.mp3
```

But if I create a shell script, `radio.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
cvlc http://5.20.223.18/relaxfm128.mp3
```

And I try to run bash script on terminal

```
bash radio.sh
```

Then I get multiple errors:

```
main input error: open of `http://5.20.223.18/relaxfm128.mp3
main input error: Your input can't be opened
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'http://5.20.223.18/relaxfm128.mp3
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: can you open the URL with other players?

Comment: Yes, i can. URL stream is fine if it is your concern.

Comment: Interesting question. Try to add -vvv to cvlc cmd line and strace your script?

Comment: @VladimirKunschikov same result, but more detailed error.

"main access debug: connection succeeded (socket = 4)
[0xb0890] access_http access error: failed to read answer"

Comment: Does your script contain `\r\n` line endings? Perhaps vlc cannot open `http://5.20.223.18/relaxfm128.mp3\r`. The missing end quote is suspicious